# error in use of tf.app.flags

Tags: tensorflow, flags

I used `tf.app.flags` in my tensorflow program like this:

```
flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS

flags.DEFINE_string('model_dir', './models','Save checkpoint')
.
.
.
if __name__ == "__main__":    
#    main()
    tf.app.run()
```

But when run my code two time it makes this error:

```
ArgumentError: argument --model_dir: conflicting option string: --model_dir
```

I think tensorflow create a argument for --model_dir and when it run again it try to create again a argument for --model_dir, but conflicted by existence --model_dir.

are there any way two solve this problem or I used python parameters against `tf.app.falgs`?

Comment: What model are you trying to run? I suspect you are trying out one of the tutorials or `imagenet/classify_image.py` which already has a flag with the same name defined.

Comment: I write a model for kaggel facial expression.I read some tutorials for learning tensorflow and Cnn.

Comment: Right. What I was asking is, are you writing your model from scratch or are you trying to modify an existing one?

Comment: i don't modify an existing one.

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that you are working in an environment like a Jupyter/iPython notebook.

The reason you are having this issue is that the flags data seems to be maintained within the Python session. `tf.app.flags.FLAGS.__getattr__('model_dir')` is equal to  `./models`  even if you reset your variable FLAGS.

If you are using a notebook, I suggest you put your flag definitions in a separate cell. The only way that I found to reset `tf.app.flags.FLAGS` is to restart the kernel/session.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail: i faced the same problem, but cannot understand how to solve. On server i see this problem, but in local PC all is working

Comment: Are you using a Jupyter notebook on both the server and your PC? Basically, in Jupyter, if you instantiate tf.app.flags.FLAGS twice you get an error. If you put it in its own cell, then you can rerun the rest of your code without re-instantiating it.

Comment: I don't use Jupyter notebook  at all, so for me this  unappropriate. Code on local Pc and server is identical, no 2nd call tf.app.flags.FLAGS. If so, what should i do

Comment: You can explicitly delete the tf.app.flags to avoid restarting the kernel/session like this answer suggested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916921/how-to-clear-tf-flags

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
#define flags
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("age", 17, "age of user(default:20)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_boolean("drink_allow", False, "if can drink or not(default:False)")
tf.flags.DEFINE_float("weight", 55.55, "weight of user(default:55.55kg)")

FLAGS = tf.flags.FLAGS  #init flags
FLAGS._parse_flags()  # parse flags

for attr,value in FLAGS.__flags.items():
    print("attr:%s\tvalue:%s" % (attr,str(value)))
```