# TensorFlow: error in use of tf.app.flags

Tags: python, django, tensorflow

I faced the same duplicate problem as [error in use of tf.app.flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267771/error-in-use-of-tf-app-flags), but cannot understand how to solve

```
ArgumentError: argument --model_dir: conflicting option string: --model_dir
```

On server i see this problem, but in local PC all is working. I use Django 1.8.12, trying to invoke neural model from view.
this is how it working on local PC:

```
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("model_dir", None, "Directory to load model checkpoints from")
```

this is how i tried to set model dir path on server:

```
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("model_dir", "./runs/1486057482/", "Directory to load model checkpoints from")
```

but this line throw error

Comment: Looks like the `DEFINE_string` function is getting called multiple times, somehow. Without seeing the code it's hard to say more, but the solution would be to make sure it's only called once.