# How to clear tf.flags?

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I run this code twice:

```
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("batch_size", "2", "batch size for training")
```

I will get this error:

```
DuplicateFlagError: The flag 'batch_size' is defined twice. First from D:/Python/workspace/FCN_dataset/FCN.tensorflow-master/FCN.py, Second from D:/Python/workspace/FCN_dataset/FCN.tensorflow-master/FCN.py.  Description from first occurrence: batch size for training
```

I know that it's because of I redefine the default value of flag. So how can I clear flags or allow to redefine the flag's default value?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
tf.flags.FLAGS.__delattr__()
```

can delete flags, so define a function to delete all flags:

```
def del_all_flags(FLAGS):
    flags_dict = FLAGS._flags()
    keys_list = [keys for keys in flags_dict]
    for keys in keys_list:
        FLAGS.__delattr__(keys)
```

Then run:

```
del_all_flags(tf.flags.FLAGS)
```

Comment: FLAGS.remove_flag_values() has implemented this, I have updated my tensorflow, so I don't know if it is a new function, you can delete all flags just by this code:  

    FLAGS.remove_flag_values(FLAGS.flag_values_dict())